# Ajax Iterate - Repeat the AJAX Call every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

AJAX call instead of .click load - I would like the ajax to run every 3 seconds till the end of Total_Records.  Here is my AJAX code which runs `.click` of a button.

I am passing two variables 
1. id number
2. Total_Records

I would like the ajax to iterate a number of times = Total_Records.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.show_more', function() {
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        var lim = $(this).attr('Total_Records');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'moreajax.php',
            data: {
                'id': ID,
                'lim': lim
            },
            success: function(html) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#show_more_main' + ID).remove();
                    $('.postList').append(html);
                }, delay);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Method 2)  Please kindly read and recommend any better way or script improvement with examples please.  this will benefit everyone.

Note: I believe this method would be a great enhancement and re-usable to lots of people who are looking for interval runs.

The only issue is the cancel button .click is not stopping the ajax call.

```
 $('#cancel').click(function() {
        cancel = true;
    });

    $(function() {

        //If cancel variable is set to true stop new calls
        if (cancel == true) return;

        var RecordsInterval = 10 * 1000;
        var fetchRecords = function() {
            console.log('Sending DATA AJAX request...');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "fetchRecords.php",
                data: {
                    'id': ID,
                    'lim': lim
                }
            }).done(function(html) {
                $('#show_more_main' + ID).remove();
                $('#postList').append(html);
                alert("You got it champ")
                console.log('success');
                console.log('Waiting ' + (RecordsInterval / 1000) + ' seconds');
                setTimeout(fetchRecords, RecordsInterval);

            }).fail(function() {
                console.log('error');
                alert("error Champ");
                return;
            });
        }

        // Fetch Records immediately, then every 10 seconds AFTER previous request finishes
        fetchRecords();
    });
```

Comment: Use setInterval or setTimeout

Comment: @Udeesha, I already used settimeout, could you show where i can use in the above code please?  and how to use till end of total_Records?  Is it possible to replace .on('click')? how?